# Making a graphics-oriented rubix cube solver in Java

Tags: java, cube, rubiks-cube

It will look something like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/Lg6Kp]

I'm wondering what the best way of going about this is, with regard to making the GUI (Swing vs. OpenGL) and any other issues you can think of.

I'm not wedded to making it 3-D, as I could just show two-sides and the bottom, but I'd love any advice.

Comment: I would use a 3D library, but not necessarily a low-level OpenGL one (like JOGL or LWJGL) directly -- let the library to the monkey business of handling world object. It will be much more flexible to modify if started on a 3D base and "fits" the intended representation much more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Kube sample in the SDK.  It implements an OpenGL Rubix cube (motion only, no input).